# blender: cannot view objects when camera is distant

Tags: blender

I have created a scene in the blender 3D view and would
like to position the camera so that all the objects are
visible (for instance by pressing the Home key and then
pressing CTRL-ALT-Keypad0 to position the camera so that
it looks at the current view, and then pressing SHIFT-F
to activate fly view to adjust the distance to the object).

However I find that when I zoom out too much the objects
are not visible to the camera although they fall out of
the far clipping plane. How do I adjust the far clipping
plane to make it farther away so that I can take a picture
of all of the objects in the scene and render them?

(an alternative would be resizing all of the objects to
make them smaller so that they fit in the clipping area
but I would rather understand and be able to adjust the
clipping area of the camera so that it contains all the
objects I am interested in rendering).

Comment: Perhaps now I see, I have to select the camera and then in the context sensitive properties view there is an object data panel where you can mess with the focal length of the camera. Is this the best way to work around the problem I was experiencing?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming and as such I have voted to close. Unfortunately I have no proper alternative SE to suggest. I see you have asked various other Blender related questions. Perhaps you would be better off asking on a Blender forum.

Comment: Hi, yes I have posted various blender questions but also answers to several of them after I've resolved them. Unfortunately I cannot find a blender mailing list for users, there only seems to be several ones for developers.

Comment: There is [Blenderartists](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/) as well as the standard [Blender forum](http://www.blender.org/forum/).

Comment: Also, try the new [CGI stackexchange](http://cgi.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Unfortunately still in private beta AFAIK, but should be public soon.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you. I'll start by saying thank you for the post. I couldn't even figure out how to word the question, but you used the word "clipping" which ultimately led me to the answer.

I think what you were saying was right next to what I found to be the best solution. Which is to select the camera, select a lens type (i found panoramic to be useful in my case), and to locate the "Clipping" section right below the lens.

In the clipping section there is a "Start" and and "end", and by increasing the "end" it allows you to see further. I hope this helps somebody else.

BTW "Mouse move choppy and laggy with Ubuntu 12.04" isn't a programming question either when the answer was to uncheck something in compiz or to disable unity 3d, but bart took the time to +2 it anyways because this time it was beneficial to him, so ignore that forum troll and hopefully he'll crawl back under the bridge he came out of. Your post helped me and +1 to SO because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adjust the End Clipping option located in the properties of camera object.

This is the step by step:

- Select your camera
- Go to the properties panel
- Select the label with a camera icon
- Under Clipping increment the End value as needed

Good Luck!